# Magento 2: product not showing up in category unless it has certain attribute

Tags: magento2

I notice that products will only be visible in category page unless it has a certain attribute, for example, say "organic" == yes. I bought this template of templatemonster so I'm wondering if there is way to get rid of this?  thank you. 
Alex

Comment: It's better if you contact the theme owner.